# Add jquery to Mganto pages inside admin panels [wysiwig editor]

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-1.8

How can I add jQuery code inside magento2 pages? For example I have a "Contact us" page. So I can edit the content inside contact us page by

Login to Admin panel

[image]

```
admin -> content -> Pages -> Contact us
```

I want to add some jQuery code.

So I write

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
  <script>
   jQuery(function($){
    $(".mybox").on("click", function(){
             MY CODE *******
       });
 });
</script>
```

Here the problem is: I have to call `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">`

Otherwise it will not work. How can I solve this?

ie. **How can i add jquery code in wysiwig editor**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 Uses Require js

Try using

```html
<script>
require([
    'jquery'

], function ($) {
    $(".mybox").on("click", function () {
        console.log('your code starts here');

        console.log('your code ends here');
    });
});
</script>
```